# In Titanic dataset , how many relatives on the board each passenger has on average has? Calculated and return Name and Number relatives columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to solve this problem:

In Titanic dataset, calculate how many relatives on the board each passenger has on average has? Calculate and return Name and Number relatives columns

I have done so far.

```
dataset['FamilySize'] = dataset['SibSp'].count() + dataset['Parch'].count()
avarage_relatives=dataset['FamilySize'].mean()
avarage_relatives
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? post the data and code (formatted) so that your question is clearer.

Comment: I want to find out how many relatives on the board each passenger on average has? I am working on the titanic dataset. Thanks for the comment , I solved the problem.